# Keeping data for my new row from the database

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic, append, row

I have a button adding new row. But when I make a selectt for my new row is empty. I don't really know how to fill it like my original row.

JavaScript/jQuery Code:

```
var counter = 0;
var $newRow ; 
$(function(){
    $('#add_field').click(function(){
        counter += 1;
        $('#tache').append('<select id="tache' + counter + '" name="tache[]' + '" type="text"  />');
    });
});
```

Here an exemple of my original row how I fill my select.

```
<!-- tache  -->
<td>
    <span id="tache">
    <!-- dꣵt section combobox tache avec tool tip -->
    <label title="Selectdimanche">
        <select title="Selectdimanche" id="Selectdimanche" name="Selectdimanche">
        <?php
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo ' <option title="';
            echo $row['tacName'];
            echo '">';
            echo $row['tacId'];
            echo '</option>'."\n";
            $task = array();
         }
         ?>
         </select>
      </label>
     <!-- Fin section cobobox tache avec tool tip -->
    </span>
</td>
```

So How I fill my data for my new row?

Comment: Will all the selects have the same options?

Comment: yes all select I need to add in the function append will have the same number from the database and the same function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy options from first select like this:

```
var counter = 0;
$('#add_field').click(function()
{
  counter += 1;
  var select = $('<select id="tache' + counter + '" name="tache[]" type="text"  />');
  select.append($("#Selectdimanche option").clone());
  $("#tache").append(select);
});
```

example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4e2P/1/)

Comment: thanks works perfectly here the answer if people want to know